# Smarty: Array not working

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have a function that prints out the following into an array like this:

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => name`

However I am unable to `foreach` through this and I am unsure why?

```
         <ul>
             {foreach from=$array item=item}
              <li>{$item.name}</li>
            {/foreach}
         </ul>
```

**Update:**

```
{foreach item=topitem from=$getlocations}
         {foreach item=item from=$topitem}
          <option value="{$item.locationid}">{$item.name}</option>
          {/foreach}
      {/foreach}
```

**Function:**

```
function getlocations()
    {
      global $smarty;

      $query = placeholderstackoverflow;

      return $query;

      $smarty->assign('getlocations', $getlocations);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually will run through an associative arrays, assuming you're using Smarty 3.xx.

Example php code:

```
$tpl->assign('yourarray', array( 
  0 => array ( 
      'id' => 1, 
      'name' => 'name'
    )
  )
);
```

Example smarty code:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$yourarray item=item}
    <li>{$item.name}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

...generates the following HTML output:

```
<ul>
    <li>name</li>
</ul>
```

If this isn't your actual or expected result, please add more code.

Check out,

- if you're using a Smarty Version 3.xx and
- if your array really is properly formed.

**Update:**

Since you're using Smarty 2.xx, then be advised that [foreach has been changed](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) in between.

For walking through a nested array, you cannot just use one foreach, you have to use more of them. Check out [example 7.8 in the manual](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) for version 2.xx.

Comment: The behaviour is different in 2.xx. Check out example 7.8 in the 2.xx manual, this will show you how to do this in this older version of Smarty.

Comment: Thanks, I have uploaded my code  I cannot seem to get a grasp on it any help to remember this is helpful

Comment: What does Smarty show for your array, when you put a `{debug}` in your template?

Comment: I have placed `{debug} into my code and I cannot via search locate `getlocations`

Comment: Then add a `var_dump($getlocations); die();` in your php code after assigning this variable to Smarty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16756/discussion-between-jess-mckenzie-and-bjoern)